# Why is SELECT MIN(CAST(`field` as SIGNED)) rounding my result value?

Tags: mysql, sql, min

When I try to use this query

```
SELECT MIN(CAST(`field` as SIGNED))
```

The results end up being rounded. So instead of 7.56 that I should be getting I am getting 7. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

because you are using `SIGNED`, try `DECIMAL`

```
SELECT MIN(CAST(`field` as DECIMAL(10,4)))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9362/2)

Comment: Heh I just posted that, Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

...CAST(value as DECIMAL(10,5))